# Qt, What does "convert project to qmake generated project" do in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qmake

When fiddeling around with my project I clicked on of the project options, but I did notice any changes. Could anyone explain what this does to the project?

Running Qt 4.8.0 plugin in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ability of qmake to generate .vcproj from a .pro file. So you should read qmake documentation to create a right .pro file.

Comment: Why do I want to generate a .vcproj file? Does this mean that vs will no longer read from the .pro file?

Comment: Don't have additinal files in this project folder compared to the one that is not qmake generated. Cannot see any difference